# Strange Error in Dropbox Sync Api for Android

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, dropbox-api

I noticed that on some devices I always get `NullPointerException` when I call `DbxAccountManager.getInstance`, but most of the time and on most devices the code works without any problem.

Here is what I am basically doing:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);

        //some initialization 

    mDbxAcctMgr = DbxAccountManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext(), appKey, appSecret);
}
```

Where `DbxAccountManager.getInstance` calls Dropbox's Sync API SDK.

Here is the trace:

```
04-20 22:36:52.565: E/AndroidRuntime(551): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
04-20 22:36:52.575: E/AndroidRuntime(551): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.nobeid.XXX/com.nobeid.XXX.Settings}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-20 22:36:52.575: E/AndroidRuntime(551):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2401)
04-20 22:36:52.575: E/AndroidRuntime(551):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2417)
04-20 22:36:52.575: E/AndroidRuntime(551):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2100(ActivityThread.java:116)
04-20 22:36:52.575: E/AndroidRuntime(551):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794)
04-20 22:36:52.575: E/AndroidRuntime(551):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-20 22:36:52.575: E/AndroidRuntime(551):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-20 22:36:52.575: E/AndroidRuntime(551):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4203)
04-20 22:36:52.575: E/AndroidRuntime(551):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-20 22:36:52.575: E/AndroidRuntime(551):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-20 22:36:52.575: E/AndroidRuntime(551):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
04-20 22:36:52.575: E/AndroidRuntime(551):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:549)
04-20 22:36:52.575: E/AndroidRuntime(551):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-20 22:36:52.575: E/AndroidRuntime(551): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-20 22:36:52.575: E/AndroidRuntime(551):  at com.dropbox.sync.android.DbxAccountManager.validateAppContext(DbxAccountManager.java:432)
04-20 22:36:52.575: E/AndroidRuntime(551):  at com.dropbox.sync.android.DbxAccountManager.getInstance(DbxAccountManager.java:106)
04-20 22:36:52.575: E/AndroidRuntime(551):  at com.dropbox.sync.android.DbxAccountManager.getInstance(DbxAccountManager.java:99)
04-20 22:36:52.575: E/AndroidRuntime(551):  at com.nobeid.XXX.Settings.onCreate(Settings.java:198)
04-20 22:36:52.575: E/AndroidRuntime(551):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1123)
04-20 22:36:52.575: E/AndroidRuntime(551):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2364)
04-20 22:36:52.575: E/AndroidRuntime(551):  ... 11 more
```

Does anyone know how to solve this issue. Any thread would help.

**Edit 1:**

Here is DbxAccountManager `getInstance` taken from Dropbox's SDK

```
static DbxAccountManager getInstance(Context applicationContext, DbxConfig config) {
    if (null == applicationContext) throw new NullPointerException("applicationContext shouldn't be null.");
    if (null == config) throw new NullPointerException("config shouldn't be null.");

    AppConfigStrings appStrings = validateAppContext(applicationContext, config);
    CoreConfig coreConfig = new CoreConfig(config, CoreConfig.Hosts.DEFAULT, appStrings.userAgent, appStrings.appVersion, appStrings.deviceId);

    synchronized (sInitializeLock) {
        if (null == sInstance) {
            sInstance = new DbxAccountManager(new CoreAccountManager(applicationContext, coreConfig));
        }
        else if (!config.equals(sInstance.mAcctMgr.getConfig())) {
             throw new ConfigurationMismatchException("Dropbox.ensureInitialized called with different configuration.");
        }

        return sInstance;
    }
}
```

and `validateAppContext`:

```
private static AppConfigStrings validateAppContext(Context appContext, DbxConfig config)
{
    Context testContext = appContext.getApplicationContext();
    if (testContext != appContext) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("The provided context wasn't an application context.");
    }

    PackageInfo pi = null;
    try
    {
        PackageManager pm = appContext.getPackageManager();
        pi = pm.getPackageInfo(appContext.getPackageName(), 4101);
    }
    catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e)
    {
        CoreLogger.getGlobal().logAndThrow(TAG, new RuntimeException("Unable to get package info for app package.", e));
    }

    CoreAssert.isTrue(null != pi);

    Set requiredActivities = new HashSet();
    requiredActivities.add(DbxAuthActivity.class.getName());
    requiredActivities.add(AuthActivity.class.getName());
    for (ActivityInfo info : pi.activities) {
        requiredActivities.remove(info.name);
    }
    if (!requiredActivities.isEmpty()) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Required Sync API Activity isn't included in application manifest: " + TextUtils.join(", ", requiredActivities));
    }

    Set requiredServices = new HashSet();
    requiredServices.add(DbxSyncService.class.getName());
    for (ServiceInfo info : pi.services) {
        requiredServices.remove(info.name);
    }
    if (!requiredServices.isEmpty()) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Required Sync API Service isn't included in application manifest: " + TextUtils.join(", ", requiredServices));
    }

    Set requiredPermissions = new HashSet();
    requiredPermissions.add("android.permission.INTERNET");
    requiredPermissions.add("android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE");
    for (String perm : pi.requestedPermissions) {
        requiredPermissions.remove(perm);
    }
    if (!requiredPermissions.isEmpty()) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Required Sync API permission isn't requested in application manifest: " + TextUtils.join(", ", requiredPermissions));
    }

    AuthActivity.checkAppBeforeAuth(appContext, config.appKey, false);

    String locale = Locale.getDefault().toString();

    StringBuilder sbUserAgent = new StringBuilder();
    sbUserAgent.append(appContext.getPackageName()).append('/').append(pi.versionCode);
    sbUserAgent.append(' ').append("DropboxSync/").append(SDK_VERSION_NAME);
    sbUserAgent.append(" (Android; ").append(CoreAndroidUtil.getSystemVersion()).append("; ").append(Build.MANUFACTURER).append(" ").append(Build.MODEL).append(" ").append(Build.CPU_ABI).append("; ").append(locale).append(")");

    StringBuilder sbAppVersion = new StringBuilder();
    sbAppVersion.append(pi.versionCode).append(' ');
    sbAppVersion.append("Dropbox-Sync-Sdk-Android/").append(SDK_VERSION_NAME);
    return new AppConfigStrings(sbUserAgent.toString(), sbAppVersion.toString(), CoreAndroidUtil.getDeviceId(appContext));
}
```

and line 432 is: `requiredServices.remove(info.name);`

**Edit 2:**
Removed irrelevant (misleading) stuff from question. (thanks CommonsWare)

Comment: "I always get NullPointerException when I call getApplicationContext()" -- not according to this stack trace. According to this stack trace, you get a `NullPointerException` when calling `getInstance()` on `DbxAccountManager`. If the Dropbox code is open source, you can see what's on that line. Otherwise, contact their developer support team, assuming that they have one.

Comment: @CommonsWare Let me rephrase my issue: On some devices `getApplicationContext()` always throws the `NPE` and on others it never does. The ratio of the devices on which the code works is much higher though. Thanks for your answer, Ill look into it and get back when I can

Comment: "On some devices getApplicationContext() always throws the NPE and on others it never does" -- I repeat: this stack trace does not show `getApplicationContext()` throwing a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: @CommonsWare I've edited my question with the `getInstance()` function from Dropbox's SDK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After contacting Dropbox's devs and some heavy debugging, it turned out that the issue was caused by the Sync SDK after some undocumented behavior on some os versions. A fix will be issued in their next API update (1.0.8).